# Обертывание изображения / фигуры вокруг с обоих сторон двумя столбцами текста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

***Я пытаюсь обернуть текст вокруг изображения с обеих сторон, следующим образом:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>
                        There’s nothing like the feeling of driving a brand new luxury car or fully equipped SUV – especially if it’s free!  That’s right!  As part of B-Epic’s Compensation Plan, one of the awesome ways we reward our Brand Partners is with a car payment bonus of $500 per month.
                    </p> 
                    <p>
                        With our one-of-a-kind Car Bonus program, you only need to focus on one simple thing: Get 4 Brand Partners on the $89.95 package and then just teach them to do the same thing. Get 4, teach 4... it doesn't get any easier than that.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        You earn the Car Bonus by purchasing a $89.95 pack or higher and sponsoring four Brand Partners at that same package level or higher who also sponsor four Brand Partners each at that package level or higher.  You are paid this bonus every month that you maintain the qualifications for it.

                    </p>
        </div>
                <img src="images\img3.jpg" class="element" alt="image">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>What’s even better is that instead of requiring you to drive a specific make and model, you get to pick out any car (or truck, SUV, or even motorcycle) that you want…in the color of your choice!  Buy it or lease it – it’s completely up to you! 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS для класса элемента, используемого в теге изображения:

```
.element
   {
 shape-outside: circle(50%);
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;

 }
```

Поделитесь кодом, чтобы получить эффект, подобный изображенному на изображении выше.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [wrapping two columns of text around an image/shape from both sides html css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52867877/7394871) от участника  [@mehmood khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7014609/mehmood-khan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52867877/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вот идея, основанная на [этом предыдущем ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55278325/8620333), где я добавлю коэффициент `margin`, чтобы контролировать расстояние между текстом и изображением:

```css
div.box {
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  --R:100px; /* radius */
  --m:5px;   /* margin */
  --t:10px;  /* distance from top */
}

div.box p {
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: initial;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.box p:before {
  content: "";
  width: var(--R);
  height: calc(2*var(--R));
  padding:var(--m) 0 var(--m) var(--m);
  margin-top:var(--t);
  background:var(--img) content-box;
  background-size:200% 100%;
  shape-outside: circle(var(--R) at var(--d,right) calc(-1*var(--m)) top calc(50% + var(--t)/2));
  float: right;
  border-radius: 500px 0 0 500px;
  margin-right:calc(-1*var(--m));
}

div.box p:last-child:before {
  float: left;
  padding:var(--m) var(--m) var(--m) 0;
  --d:left;
  background-position:right;
  border-radius:0 500px 500px 0;
  margin-left:calc(-1*var(--m));
  margin-right:0;
}

*,*::before,*::after {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1011/400/400.jpg)">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/248/400/400.jpg);--R:80px;--m:10px;--t:30px;">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>

</div>
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/400/400.jpg);--R:150px;--m:2px;--t:30px;">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure,  illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipisicing elit. Ex sapiente iste   asp ernatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conse quuntur iure, cumque laud antium quidem ratione perfe rendis minima digniss <br><br>Sed, placeat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Ex sap iente iste repudi andae aspe rnatur, illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure,  illum esse veniam eligendi, dolor conseq uuntur iure, 
  </p>

</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связанный вопрос, если вам нужен противоположный эффект (текст внутри круга):  [How can I ensure that text is inside rounded div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19909266/8620333)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654583/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

В наши дни `shape-outside` может быть вариантом:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside
>
> Свойство CSS `shape-outside` определяет фигуру, которая может быть
> непрямоугольной, вокруг которой должно быть заключено соседнее
> встроенное содержимое. По умолчанию встроенное содержимое обтекает
> поле поля; `shape-outside` предоставляет способ настройки этого
> обтекания, которое позволяет обтекать текстом сложные объекты, а не
> простые линии.

Мы также должны помнить о поддержке браузером [shape-outside](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)

---

Изображение или градиент можно использовать для рисования формы, чтобы текст не попал в нее.

Для круга нужно 4 части, которые можно изготовить из псевдоэлементов.

- идея состоит в том, чтобы начать с квадратного прямоугольника и 4
  плавающих псевдо с радиальным градиентом фона, нарисованным за
  пределами круга / центра.

```css
div:not([class]) {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
}

div[class]:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background: radial-gradient( circle at bottom right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:before {
  background: radial-gradient( circle at top right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background: radial-gradient( circle at bottom left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:after {
  background: radial-gradient( circle at top left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}


/* extra */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #399;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
</div>
```

- Теперь, когда мы знаем, что наши радиальные градиенты находятся в
  нужных местах, мы можем использовать их в качестве фигур, чтобы
  отодвинуть текст от этих областей. Градиенты не будут нарисованы,
  будет использоваться только форма.

```css
div:not([class]) {
/* em is to manage the text length and so is the font-sfamily and line-height */

  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:justify;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
}

div[class]:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at bottom right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:before {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at top right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at bottom left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:after {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at top left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}


/* extra */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #399;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. 
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Мы также можем рассмотреть переменные CSS, чтобы упростить настройку
  кода в зависимости от текстового содержимого:

```css
div:not([class]) {
/* em is to manage the text length and so is the font-sfamily and line-height */
  
  --s:10em; /*Size of the circle */

  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:justify;
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:5px;
}

div[class]:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
  /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at bottom right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:before {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at top right, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at bottom left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}

div[class][id]:after {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient( circle at top left, transparent 69%, red 69%);
}


/* extra */
body {
  background: #399;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes . 
</div>

<div style="--s:20em">
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum 
</div>
```

- Вот еще один синтаксис для радиального градиента:

```css
div:not([class]) {
/* em is to manage the text length and so is the font-sfamily and line-height */
  
  --s:10em; /*Size of the circle */

  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:justify;
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:5px;
}

div[class]:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
  /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 100%, red 0);
}

div[class][id]:before {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 100%, red 0);
}

div[class]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 100%, red 0);
}

div[class][id]:after {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 100%, red 0);
}


/* extra */
body {
  background: #399;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. 
</div>

<div style="--s:20em">
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci. orci. rat ultri cies Pel 
</div>
```

- Затем мы можем добавить дополнительную переменную для имитации
  заполнения:

```css
div:not([class]) {
/* em is to manage the text length and so is the font-sfamily and line-height */
  
  --s:10em; /*Size of the circle */
  --p:0px;  /*padding*/

  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:justify;
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:5px;
}

div[class]:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
  /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent calc(100% - var(--p)), red 0);
}

div[class][id]:before {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent calc(100% - var(--p)), red 0);
}

div[class]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  height: calc(var(--s)/2);
  width: calc(var(--s)/2);
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent calc(100% - var(--p)), red 0);
}

div[class][id]:after {
 /*background*/ shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent calc(100% - var(--p)), red 0);
}


/* extra */
body {
  background: #399;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. 
</div>

<div style="--s:20em;--p:15px">
  <div class=shape></div>
  <div class=shape id=idAttribute></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in sociis. Pel lentes que ultri cies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget orci, tinci dunt place rat in  
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485135/7394871) от участника  [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus).</sub>